# Fluent NHibernate - HasMany().WithKeyColumnName

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I just got the latest version of Fluent from Google code and it seems some of the mapping has changed since I last used it.

Previously I could Map a relationship using the following when the id I was joining on had a different name in the second table

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithTableName("tbl_Roles").WithKeyColumn("RoleId");
```

How is done in the latest release of Fluent?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles)
  .WithTableName("tbl_Roles")
  .KeyColumns.Add("RoleId");
```

Multiple column support was added, so the method signature needed to be improved to make it clear what's happening.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles)
  .WithTableName("tbl_Roles")
  .KeyColumnNames.Add("RoleId");
```